# Magento table rates not updating to different amount

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We had a strange problem (see below) and in the end it is solved by first changing the table rates to a different way of calculating, by weight instead of country and then changing it back. After changing it back it just worked, so I think something blocked the database.

We have a strange problem with our Magento shop and do not find the problem. We have set the table rates to charge 2,95 till 30 euro and 0.00 by orders of 30 euro and more. When we go to the checkout page and we have a amount that is more then 30 euro he is not updating.

there is also something else strange, when I change the shipping method from Table rates to flat rate and free shipping, he still shows the table rates and does not show the two different rate.

It looks like it has to do with the cookies that are set by Magento or something like that. We have set exactly the same details at a other shop at the same server and there is everything working fine.

By config / system / web / session cookie management we have tried to set the cookie to 1 day (84000), but this did not work.

I have also looked in the errors it gives and it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'observe' of null cookie.js:11  (see printscreen below)

[image]

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flush cache storage
2. Refresh cache

To do so go to Admin > System > Cache Control

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is not it. We have even disabled cache management and deleted all cache manually from the server. Other ideas?

Comment: At the moment 1 website with 2 stores and a couple of store vies. I also just updated my question, because I saw a .js error for cookies

Comment: It is surely not related cookies problem. This may be funny - it sounds lie you are changing backend for one installation and testing frontend in other installation

Comment: If you look there, we have set now the table rates and with 30 euro and more 0, so free

Comment: Thanks, I can not see what rules (from frontend) Can you show me screenshot of xml/csv file that you have used to import table rate.

Comment: Dear Krishna, Now it is working again, in my question I set what we did. It was really strange, after 5 hours of trying we changed the way of calculating and set it back and then it worked ok again. Never seen this before..